# Can I safely install Android system updates with disabled Gapps?

Tags: adb, updates, google, ota-update, side-loading

On my Nexus 5x for personal choices I disabled all the Gapps (Google apps) via the Settings menu, included "Google Play Services" and "Google Services Framework". With these two apps disabled the Software Update screen is not available at all, so I'd like to install the May 2016 security patch with the Adb Sideload method.

The question is, do I risk any bootloop or any other issue if I manually update while those apps are disabled?

I would say no for several Gapps because if so they wouldn't even let me disable them, but the two mentioned above are required to get the update screen, that's why I'm worried about it. The phone has the stock ROM, no unlocked bootloader, nothing unusual.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I answer myself, just updated and everything has gone smooth! Nice!